# How Do I Make An Engine Nozzle?

Tags: modeling

I want to make a rocket engine nozzle but I don't know how to curve a cone into its point and make it hollow. I thought about using a torus or cylinder but I wouldn't know how to recreate the shape. (Google Raptor Engine)

Comment: This is a very broad question that would require an in depth tutorial of modelling techniques to answer properly. Perhaps start by watching some tutorial videos such as this one - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r6xwvrZuOek

Comment: That video doesn't really help me. If I could extrude this (https://imgur.com/a/QDkVJn0) and curve it in slowly that would be ideal.